# section de bioenvenida

Tags: html

Les comento que soy nuevo en esto de la programación, y estoy haciendo mi primer sitio web, estoy haciendo la *home* y me quede trabado en la sección de bienvenida.

La *section* contiene un `div` con el titulo de *LOREM IPSUM SIT AMET...* y debajo va a otro `div` que va a contener el contenido que describe de que trata la pagina, osea una `section` donde va a tener un `div` para el titulo y otro `div` para el contenido.

Alguien me dice como lo puedo hacer?? si hay otra alternativa a los dos divs mejor, mi idea es que haya una línea divisora entre el titulo y la especificación.

Gracias! De paso les mando el render de mi home.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola, bienvenid@ a StackOverflow en español, te sugiero hacer el [tour] para que tengas una mejor idea sobre el funcionamiento de la pagina y puedas dar a conocer tu pregunta de mejor manera. También puedes revisar [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No he entendido muy bien tu problema, pero creo que lo que quieres es saber como hacer la sección de bienvenida, aquí tienes un ejemplo de algo parecido a lo que tienes en la imagen:

```css
.bienvenida {width:80%;background:black;}
.titulo {color:orange;text-align:center;padding-top:1px;}
.descripcion {color:white;padding:5px;}
```

```html
<section class="bienvenida">
  <div class="titulo">
    <h2>Sección de bienvenida</h2>
  </div>
  <hr/>
  <div class="descripcion">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed varius ullamcorper odio, auctor condimentum nulla egestas eget. Nullam sodales in nibh eu interdum. Suspendisse accumsan erat neque, id maximus quam posuere id. Praesent hendrerit ex at tempus facilisis.</p>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: lal, te hago otra pregunta: porque a las divs las encerraste solo con la etiqueta section y no también con article si contiene texto?

Comment: Aunque sea texto no es necesario, la etiqueta article se usa sobre todo para articulos de un blog, o también para posts en un foro o comentarios, aqui tienes más información sobre article: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_article.asp

Comment: yo pensé que los divs son cajas por eso dije si se podía hacer en dos divs.

Comment: @diegui Stack Overflow no es un foro donde vas publicando posts y más posts para comunicarte con otros usuarios o añadir nueva información. Es un sitio de preguntas y respuestas (Q&A), donde hay una sección para las pregunta y otra para las respuestas. Si tienes comentarios sobre una publicación puedes añadir comentarios debajo de la misma, y si quieres añadir nueva información a la pregunta (o a una respuesta) puedes darle al botón de editar. Completa el [tour] para aprender más sobre el sitio y lee [ask] y [answer] para más información.